# Can it cause battery damage to use 10.5W phone charger(not PD) for my MacBook Air M1?

Tags: macbook-pro, battery, charging

I heard using a low wattage charger can damage the battery but I'm not sure if it's really true. The Apple's official document just says the speed will be low but not mentions about the damage.
What do you think about this problem?